make4ht with option for auxiliary files in Windows
I have this file Questions\285.tex:
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{center}
\textbf{line1}
\textit{line2}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
\end{document}

I want to convert it to html. I am using:
make4ht Questions/285.tex -d output

It generates the html and css files in the output directory:
\..\currentdir>dir output

23/06/2024  13:45    <DIR>          .
23/06/2024  14:01    <DIR>          ..
23/06/2024  14:01             6.274 285.css
23/06/2024  14:01             1.022 285.html
               2 archivos          7.296 bytes
               2 dirs  309.117.435.904 bytes libres

However it generates several auxiliary files in current directory:
\..\currentdir>dir


23/06/2024  14:01    <DIR>          .
23/06/2024  12:39    <DIR>          ..
23/06/2024  14:01                83 285.4ct
23/06/2024  14:01                76 285.4tc
23/06/2024  14:01                76 285.aux
23/06/2024  14:01             6.274 285.css
23/06/2024  14:01            21.356 285.dvi
23/06/2024  14:01             1.022 285.html
23/06/2024  14:01            10.989 285.idv
23/06/2024  14:01             7.398 285.lg
23/06/2024  14:01            32.318 285.log
23/06/2024  14:01                15 285.tmp
23/06/2024  14:01                33 285.xref

How can I make make4ht to move those files to an aux_output directory?

Recent versions of make4ht supports the --build-dir (or -B) option. It uses the specified directory for the build process, so all temporary files should be located here. In you case, you could use this command:
$ make4ht -d output -B aux_output Questions/285.tex 

